# when Array count 0 collection view does not show data

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a tableView that has 4 cells and in the second and fourth cells, I add collection view. the problem is that in the second cell when the array count is 1 the collection view does not get called. as soon as array count is greater than 1 the collection view shows data accordingly.

I am doing this for tableView -:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewAllCell") as! ViewAllCell
    cell.countLbl.text = String(historyArray.count)
    return cell
} else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoDownloadTableViewCell") as! VideoDownloadTableViewCell
    cell.collectionViewOne.layoutSubviews()
    cell.collectionViewOne.reloadData()
    return cell
} else if indexPath.row == 2 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlatformTableViewCell") as! PlatformTableViewCell
    return cell
} else if indexPath.row == 3 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlateformViewTableViewCell") as! PlateformViewTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

And this for collection view cellForRow -:

```
if collectionView.tag == 100 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoViewCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoViewCell
    cell.cornerView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cornerView.frame.size.width/2
    cell.cornerView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.cornerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    return cell
}
if collectionView.tag == 101 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DashboardCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! DashboardCollectionCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.socialPlatFormName.text = kConstant.plateformName.facebook
        cell.socialPlatFormName.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "0858F2")
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.socialPlatFormName.text = kConstant.plateformName.instagram
        cell.socialPlatFormName.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "D73F8C")
        cell.socialPlatFormImage.image = UIImage(named: "instagram")
    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.socialPlatFormName.text = kConstant.plateformName.snapChat
        cell.socialPlatFormName.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "D6AE12")
        cell.socialPlatFormImage.image = UIImage(named: "snapchat")
    }
    return cell
}
return UICollectionViewCell()
```

what is wrong in this code.

Comment: When the array count is 1, the max indexPath row will be 0 so you will not go into your `if indexPath.row == 1` block. With your current logic, the minimum array size for a collectionview to show is 2.

Comment: @ShawnFrank you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Note that your `if indexPath.row == 0... else if indexPath.row == 1...` code would be cleaner as a switch statement. You also need to handle cases where the indexPath.row > 3, and a default case on a switch statement would be perfect for that.

Comment: @DuncanC yes. I forgot to remove the tag. I will delete my comment

Answer (score 1):

When the array count is 1, the max indexPath row will be 0, hence this condition will be false `if indexPath.row == 1` and so your collection view will not be created.

With your current logic, the minimum array size for a collectionview to show is 2.

Finally, a couple of nice suggestions by Duncan, the code would be cleaner if you used a `switch` rather than an `if-else` block and also you need to take care of scenarios where `indexPath.row > 3`, something like:

```
switch indexPath.row
{
    case 0:
    // do what you want
    case 1:
    // set up collection view
    case 2:
    // do something else
    case 3:
    // do something else
    default:
    // handle cases where the array size is
    // greater than 4
}
```

**Update**

The output you get has nothing to do with using an `if` or a `switch` but with the logic of your implementation.

An array's index starts at 0, so the first element in an array is at index 0.

```
var array = [5, 6, 10, 11, 14]

// this will print 5 because an array's index starts at `0`
print(array[0])
```

Similarly, a UITableView's row and section, starts at `0`, not at 1.

**When you check `indexPath.row == 0`, you are not checking if the table has 0 rows, you are checking if the current cell is in row 0 (which is the first row)**

```
// this is the first row in your table view
indexPath.row == 0 

// this is the second row in your table view
indexPath.row == 1
```

So when your array has a count of 1, the following happens

```
switch indexPath.row
{
    case 0:
    // This gets executed when array size is at least 1
    // Since the array size is 1, this case gets executed
    
    case 1:
    // This only gets executed when array size is at least 2
    // Executing this case means the table has at least 2 rows
    // Since array size is 1, table view won't have a 2nd row
    // Not executed since the array size is 1
    // Hence, you won't see the collection view
    
    case 2:
    // This case only gets executed when array size is at least 3
    // Executing this case means the table has at least 3 rows
    // Not executed since the array size is 1
    
    case 3:
    // This case gets executed when array size is at least 4
    // Executing this case means the table has at least 4 rows
    // Not executed since the array size is 1
    
    default:
    // This gets executed when array size is at least 5
    // Executing this case means the table has more than 4 rows
    // Not executed since the array size is 1
}
```

If you want to see the collection view when the array size is 1, you need to initialize the collection view when `indexPath.row == 0`

Comment: this code does not work for me still when the array count is 1 the collection view does not get called.

Comment: @PoornimaMishra - please see what I mentioned `With your current logic, the minimum array size for a collectionview to show is 2.`

Comment: I tried with switch case

Comment: @PoornimaMishra - it has nothing to do with using `switch`. Please see my updated explanation.

Comment: how to initialize the collection view when indexPath.row == 0 I tried everything but nothing happen @Shawn Frank

Comment: @PoornimaMishra Move this code: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoDownloadTableViewCell") as! VideoDownloadTableViewCell`  `cell.collectionViewOne.layoutSubviews()`  `cell.collectionViewOne.reloadData()` into `indexPath.row == 0` block. If that does not work, you can share this on a repository and I can offer to take a quick look.

Comment: i tried this but nothing happen

Comment: @PoornimaMishra - please prepare an isolated example of this and share your source code on github and I can have a look if you wish.